# Turn off appendix header in list of figures/tables when there are no tables or figures in any appendix

Tags: table-of-contents, appendices

My list of tables and list of figures are showing correctly for my main document, but after the main list I get a header for the appendix that looks like:

> 4.1 Last Figure...................................whatever page
>
> Appendix
>
> Figure

I do not have any figures in any of my appendices, but the header still shows. If I add a fake figure to an appendix it appears after the header.

I have tried using `\addtocontents{lof}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}}` to turn off the list of figures in appendices, and it works in that no more figures are shown after the header, but the header is still there.

I'm using a thesis .cls that I didn't write, so I'm not sure what everything does. The section that covers the list of tables/figures/contents looks like this:

```
\def\tableofcontents{\@tableof{TABLE OF CONTENTS}{}{tocpage}{toc}{}}

\def\listoffigures{
  \@tableof{LIST OF FIGURES}{Figure}{lofpage}{lof}
  {\protect\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{LIST OF FIGURES}}}

\def\listoftables{
  \@tableof{LIST OF TABLES}{Table}{lotpage}{lot}
  {\protect\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{LIST OF TABLES}}}

\def\@tableof#1#2#3#4#5{
{ % limit scope of following declarations!!
  \@restonecolfalse\if@twocolumn\@restonecoltrue\onecolumn\fi
  \addtolength{\textheight}{-40pt}       % -24-16
  %\addtolength{\majorheadskip}{-40pt}    % -24-16
  \addtolength{\headheight}{52pt}        %  36+16
  \addtolength{\headsep}{-12pt}          % -12
  \begin{center}
  \chapter*{#1}
  \end{center}
  #5
  \relax\markboth{#1}{#1}
  \hbox to \hsize{#2 \hfil Page}
  \singlespace
  \setcounter{#3}{0}
  \setcounter{listofheading}{1}  % change from 0 to 1
  \def\@oddhead{\vbox to \headheight{\vspace{4pt}
    \hbox to \hsize{\hfil\rm\thepage} \vfil
    \ifnum\value{#3}=1
      \ifnum\value{listofheading}=2
        \hbox to \hsize{Appendix\hfil} \vspace{4pt} \fi
      \ifnum\value{listofheading}=1
        \stepcounter{listofheading} \fi
      \hbox to \hsize{#2 \hfil Page}
    \else
      \setcounter{#3}{1}
    \fi
    }}
  \def\@evenhead{\vbox to \headheight{\vspace{4pt}
    \hbox to \hsize{\rm\thepage\hfil} \vfil
    \ifnum\value{#3}=1
      \ifnum\value{listofheading}=2
        \hbox to \hsize{Appendix\hfil} \vspace{4pt} \fi
      \ifnum\value{listofheading}=1
        \stepcounter{listofheading} \fi
      \hbox to \hsize{#2 \hfil Page}
    \else
      \setcounter{#3}{1}
    \fi
    }}
  \@starttoc{#4}  \if@restonecol\twocolumn\fi
  % \newpage
}}
```

I have tried removing everything in the `@tableof` definition except the `@starttoc` line and the header still appears. How do I get the lists to not show headers for sections that are empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a compilable example or at least a link to your class file, it's hard to say what's going on. The `\@tableof` macro isn't the culprit -- it temporarily switches to `\onecolumn`, changes the page margins and sets up the headers for even and odd LoF/LoT pages. I suggest to have a look at the definition of `\appendix` in your class file -- if this macro includes a line like

```
\addtocontents{lof}{Appendix}
```

copy the `\appendix` definition into the preamble of your document (to be sure, enclose it within `\makeatletter`/`\makeatother`) and comment out the above-mentioned line.